Game controller profiles are not working in macOS Ventura
I have an Xbox wireless controller connected via Bluetooth and a DualShock 4 controller connected via a USB cable that I'm using on my Intel mac running macOS 13.6.5. The system recognizes both controllers, and I tried remapping its buttons in the Game Controllers system settings by creating a profile for it that applies to all games and assigning it to the controller, but it has absolutely no effect at all. I've tested in several games at this point.
Is this feature just broken? Or is there something subtle I'm doing wrong?
